# React form + localstorage won't update values

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hook-form

Currently I am working on a form with the use of react hook forms and I want to save input from a user in the localstorage. At this moment whenever I change the value of the input when loaded from localstorage the input wont change.

When I console.log the event from the onchange method I don't get a log so it didn't trigger the onchange and thats where my problem is. I want that when a user wants to change anything in the form that it should update again.

I have searched on google but I can't find any related problem and so no solution. Since I am a beginner in react I have no clue to solve it myself.

The onchange function is in a functional component same as the input components is only functional.

This is the onchange function that contains the input event.

```
const onChange = event => {
    localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
};
```

This is the input compontent

```
<Input key={index} field={item} formFunction={register({required:true})} checkChange={handleChange} onChange={e => onChange(e)} value={localStorage.getItem(item.label) || ''} errors={errors} selectCheck={handleCountryChange} touched={touched} />
```

And this is the input compontents code

```
    return (
        <div className={props.field.grid}>
            <div className={props.field.inputClass}>
                    <input 
                        type={props.field.type} 
                        name={props.field.name} 
                        className={props.field.class} 
                        id={props.field.label} 
                        data-save="persist" 
                        onBlur={props.checkChange} 
                        style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }} 
                        onChange={props.onChange}
                        value={props.value}
                    />
                
                
                <label className="left" htmlFor={props.field.label}>{props.field.label}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: You are getting the data from the local storage with the key `item.label`, yet you store it with the key `event.target.id`. Are those 2 the same?

Comment: Yes that are the same values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is you are using the local storage to try and update the state of the app so the render function will not get re called and display the new inputted. ( unless you can show more code and you are indeed updating that this.props.value )?

I would suggest looking up local state within component for react, it will make things 10x easier in the future:

[React state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

[Functional component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

You are best creating a local state in your constructor if it is an class component e.g., same can be achieved if it is a functional component just slightly different.

```
this.state = {
 inputVariable: ""
}
```

then when ever your change this variable(in your onchange function using set state):

```
 setstate({
  inputVariable: valueToUpdate
})
```

your input components value field should be populated with this.state.inputVariable, so as you change the value it will trigger on change and then update the state which will cause a re render of your UI.

if you additionally also to save it to local storage you can do so like you already have.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a functional component so this.state wont work

Comment: @iJokerAssassin check this out for functional component states:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Would there a way to prevent creating a [value, setValue] for each input? Cause this would be very unhandy

Comment: @iJokerAssassin if your going to populate these fields, i believe you are going to need a way of modifying the state of each input field. ( they need to be stored some where )